# Is it possible to set env from a pipeline inside a jupyter notebook cell?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

running this command inside a jupyter notebook cell

```
!whereis cudnn.h
```

gets this output

```
cudnn: /usr/include/cudnn.h
```

running this command inside a jupyter notebook cell

```
%env CUDNN_H_PATH=/usr/include/cudnn.h
```

sets an environment variable

running this command inside a jupyter notebook cell

```
%env CUDNN_H_PATH=$(whereis cudnn.h)
```

gets this

```
!echo $CUDNN_H_PATH
$(whereis cudnn.h)
```

## question

Is it possible to set the output of `!whereis cudnn.h` to environment variable `CUDNN_H_PATH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible: store the result of `!whereis cudnn.h`, which will be a list, and get the first item. Then simply pass it to `%env`:

```
path = !whereis ls # using ls instead of cudnn.h, but would work either way
path = path[0]
%env CUDNN_H_PATH=$path

!echo $CUDNN_H_PATH
ls: /bin/ls
```

However, if you're looking to get only the path from `!whereis cudnn.h` (without the `cudnn:`), you might do something like this:

```
path = !whereis ls
path = path[0].split(' ')[1]
%env CUDNN_H_PATH=$path

!echo $CUDNN_H_PATH
/bin/ls
```

You'll have to watch out for `IndexError` if `!whereis cudnn.h` doesn't find whatever you're looking for.